# Set AutoIncrement value with Subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I am trying to provide the value for auto increment value through the subquery in mysql

I tried with this command

```
alter table xxx auto_increment = (select max(id) from xxx) ;
```

But am getting the syntax error as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(select max(id) from xxx)' at line 1

Please anyone help me on this issue....Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Yeah, that is not possible. The parser does not allow you to place a subquery for the query you are trying.

Comment: Just do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql for this:

```
select concat("alter table foo auto_increment=",max(id)) from foo into @maxid;
prepare setautoinc from @maxid;
execute setautoinc;
deallocate prepare setautoinc;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O8JKa3gL)

Comment: @Akina only if the value you are setting exists. Just `alter table foo auto_increment = 123` does the same

Comment: As I have said in my answer - if provided or above value exists. From the other side - you select this value, so it cannot not exist :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set AUTO_INCREMENT by this way - new AUTO_INCREMENT value is literal and cannot be an expression.

To achieve your goal it is enough to set AUTO_INCREMENT to 1. For this statement the provided value is always checked, and if some rows exists and it must be above provided value then it is adjusted to `MAX(AI_column) + 1` automatically.

### DEMO:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT);
SELECT * FROM test;      -- rows id=1,2 inserted
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;  -- AUTO_INCREMENT = 3
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| test | CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

```
ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;           -- set value above current
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;  -- AUTO_INCREMENT = 10 -- specified value applied
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| test | CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

```
ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;           -- set value below current
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;  -- AUTO_INCREMENT = 3 -- value adjusted to MAX(id)+1
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| test | CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uJJlKVNq)